# Using Kpfonts' mathbb in amsfonts

Tags: fonts, kpfonts, blackboard

I'm trying to use `amsfonts`, or more precisely, the math font of `amsfonts`, but I don't really like how the blackboard bold looks. Neither do I enjoy the look of something like `dsfonts`, or many other options. But the way that `kpfonts` has implemented blackboard bold is very much to my taste - how do I "import" that blackboard bold font?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum $\mathbb{N,Z,Q,R,C}$ lorem ipsum

\[f_i 1_{[-n,n]}\uparrow f_i,\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know a lot about the technical aspects of LaTeX - I pretty much only know that I use MiKTeX and how to define some small commands. But if it doesn't collide with MiKTeX, then sure, I'll use LuaLaTeX and any package that fixes the problem.

Comment: MikTeX provides executables and fonts for both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (and several other TeX engines too, for that matter). *How* to invoke MikTeX's pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX executables is determined by the front-end/editor -- about which you haven't provided much information so far.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess at TeXworks (@Mico).  Requaero, does that sound familiar?

Comment: I use TeXmaker, actually, so switching to LuaLaTeX wasn't so difficult. But I ended up using egreg's answer as it was easier than making the switch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking for `mathbb` in `kpfonts.sty` we find that there are two choices, with or without serifs. You want the serif font, so we see

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{jkp\kp@famillem syb\kp@widerm}{m}{n}% rmmathbb
\SetSymbolFont{AMSb}{bold}{U}{jkp\kp@famillem syb\kp@widerm}{bx}{n}
```

OK, now we need to see what `\kp@famillem` and `\kp@widerm` mean. The former is easy: it means `l` if we want the “light” fonts and it's empty otherwise. For the latter, it is `w` if “wide math” is desired and empty otherwise.

That's enough. We don't want a symbol font, but just an alphabet, so

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{jkpsyb}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{bold}{U}{jkpsyb}{bx}{n}
```

should be what you need. Let's try.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{jkpsyb}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{bold}{U}{jkpsyb}{bx}{n}

\begin{document}

$a+\mathbb{A}+\mathbb{Z}$

\boldmath
$a+\mathbb{A}+\mathbb{Z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing and able to compile your document with LuaLaTeX, you may take advantage of the fact that the `kpfonts` math font family has recently become available in OpenType format. This is great as it lets you use some high-level options of the `unicode-math` package to activate just the kpfont-type math font just for the blackboard-bold range.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
% Latin Modern is a clone of Computer Modern
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} 
\setmathfont{KpMath Regular}[range=bb, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum $\mathbb{N,Z,Q,R,C}$ lorem ipsum
\[
f_i 1_{[-n,n]}\uparrow f_i,\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}
\]

$\symup{NZQRC}$ vs $\symbb{NZQRC}$

$\mathrm{NZQRC}$ vs $\mathbb{NZQRC}$
\end{document}
```